# How to move object over a line and delete old object so it doesn't leave tails in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to move a ball over a line but the it's like when I changed the position it leaves the old object on the line. How do I move the object smoothly over a line in HTML5?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10, 10);
context.lineTo(400, 10);
context.stroke();


function clickToAddBall() {
    // Do something
}

function gameLoop() {
    var loop = 400;
    setInterval(function() {
        loop = loop - 10;
        drawABall(loop);
    }, 200);
}
gameLoop();

function drawABall(positionX) {

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(positionX, 10, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/z5VwL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple to solve. You should redraw the screen, or at least empty it the moment before it draws, just at this function to your gameloop:

```
 function clearScreen() {
     context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }
```

and then it should look a bit like this:

```
function gameLoop() {
    var loop = 400;
    setInterval(function() {
        loop = loop - 10;
        clearScreen();
        drawABall(loop);
    }, 200);
}
gameLoop();
```

You should also make a lineDraw function and add it inside of the loop, otherwise the line will just disappear, but that should not be much of a problem, just write the function and add it like this:

```
function gameLoop() {
    var loop = 400;
    setInterval(function() {
        loop = loop - 10;
        clearScreen();
        drawLine();
        drawABall(loop);
    }, 200);
}
gameLoop();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the canvas for each redraw.
I added

```
context.clearRect(0,0,578, 200 );
```

to the draw function...

```
function drawABall(positionX) {
      var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
      var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 5;

      context.clearRect(0,0,578, 200 );   

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(positionX, 10, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();

}
```

Just as a quick example, here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5VwL/3/

Comment: Your fiddle does not work, but your answer should be correct.